# how to catch HTTP error in Emberjs store.find method?

Tags: ember.js, find, ember-data, store, http-error

I am setting a `model` in `CustomerRoute`'s `setupController` hook as follows:

```
var self_controller = controller;
var onSuccess = function(customer) {

    var reloadSuccess = function(customer_reloaded) {
        // customer is reloaded successfully
        self_controller.set('model', customer_reloaded);
    };

    var reloadError = function(err_response_for_reload) {

        if(err_response_for_reload.status == 401) {
            terminate_session();
        }
        else {
            HTTP_error();
            self_controller.transitionTo('all_customers');
        }
    };

    // reload Model to forcefully fetch from server
    customer.reload().then(reloadSuccess).catch(reloadError);
};
var onError = function(reason) {

    if(reason.status == 401) {
        terminate_session();
    }
    else {
        HTTP_error();
        self_controller.transitionTo('all_customers');
    }
};
var customer_promise = self_controller.store.find('customer', model.id);
customer_promise.then(onSuccess).catch(onError);
```

But I am unable to catch HTTP errors (401 unauthorized, 500 Internal Server Error, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

ember-data provides a hook `ajaxError` to handle all error msgs in `DS.RestAdapter`. If you write it for ApplicationAdapter it will be used by all models based on `RestAdapter`. Here is how code looks(extracted from ember docs)

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  ajaxError: function(jqXHR) {
    var error = this._super(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR && jqXHR.status === 422) {
      var jsonErrors = Ember.$.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText)["errors"];

      return new DS.InvalidError(jsonErrors);
    } else {
      return error;
    }
  }
});
```

Link for same in ember docs http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_ajaxError